# I'm not able to create controller in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, execjs

> C:\Sites\guestbook>rails generate controller entries
>
> ```
>                                       C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect':
> ```
>
> Could not find a JavaScript runtime. 
>   See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)

```
gem install execjs
```

I installed the with the command above but are getting the error again. 
I'm trying to do this command:

```
rails generate controller entries
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to add `gem 'therubyracer'` to your Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

The gem you're using requires that you have a separate library for javascript installed on your system.  On linux, you would need to install nodeJS, rhino, or something like that through the package manager.  On Windows, I imagine you would have to do a manual installation.

If you don't want to do that, the easiest thing to do is to remove the execjs gem, unless you really need it.

Comment: I did uninstall it, but then I'm not able to run the command to generate the controller, seems like I'm stuck in a moment 22.

Comment: What command did you use to uninstall it?  You'll probably need to do a 'gem uninstall', possibly followed by 'bundle install', or something like that.